# ID auto generation for MySQL on JBoss AS 7

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jboss7.x

I need help to resolve such problem. Application needs to support several DB (MySQL, Oracle). After migration to JBoss 7 entity id auto generation was broken.
Etity example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="foo")
public class Foo {
    private Integer id;
    private String model;

    @Id 
    @SequenceGenerator(name="foo_seq_gen", sequenceName="foo_0", initialValue=1, allocationSize=1)
    @Column(name="id", updatable=false)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "foo_seq_gen")
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name="model", length=64, updatable=false)
    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }
    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }
}
```

For Oracle it works fine. But when trying to perform create operation on MySQL following error occures:

```
15:34:56,290 ERROR [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Table 'scheme.foo_0' doesn't exist
```

Thus MySQL tries to access non-existent table as sequence instead of using native autogeneration mechanism.

Does anybody know the cure?

Using "table" generator strategy didn't help.

Environment:

```
MySQL 5.5.16;
JBoss AS 7.1.0.Beta1;
Hibernate 3.6.1.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I' not sure if you need the `@SequenceGenerator` for Oracle, but with *JBoss AS 7.1.0.CR1b* and *MySQL* I have no problems with ID auto generation and this annotations:

```
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;
```